# insert new record and update existing at the same time in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my code for save and update purchase order.

```
  function save(&$purchase_data,$purchase_id)
    {
        $success=false;

        //Run these queries as a transaction, we want to make sure we do all or nothing
        $this->db->trans_start();

        if($purchase_data)
        {
            if (!$purchase_id or !$this->exists($purchase_id))
            {  
                //$purchase_data['purchase_id'] = $purchase_id = $purchase_data['purchase_id'];
                $success = $this->db->insert('purchase_order',$purchase_data);
                $post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('data');
                /*print_r($post_array);
                exit;*/
                $purchase_id=$this->db->insert_id();
                $i=0;
    foreach($post_array['cart'] as $item)
    {
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($item); echo "</pre>";
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM phppos_items WHERE item_id='".$item['product_id']."'");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $product_name=$row->name;

}
        $product_id=$item['product_id'];
        $quantity=$item['quantity'];
        $unit=$item['unit'];
        $unit_rate=$item['unit_rate'];
        $query = $this->db->query("insert into phppos_productdetails(product_id,product_name,quantity,unit,unit_rate,purchase_id) values ('$product_id','$product_name','$quantity','$unit','$unit_rate','$purchase_id')");

        $i++;
    }
            }
            else
            {

                $this->db->where('purchase_id', $purchase_id);
                $success = $this->db->update('purchase_order',$purchase_data);
                //$this->session->set_userdata('sess_products');
                $post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('sess_products');

                $i=0;
    foreach($post_array['cart'] as $item)
    {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($item); echo "</pre>";

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM phppos_items WHERE item_id='".$item['product_id']."'");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $product_name=$row->name;

}

        $product_id=$item['product_id'];
        $quantity=$item['quantity'];
        $unit=$item['unit'];
        $unit_rate=$item['unit_rate'];

        $query = $this->db->query("update phppos_productdetails set product_id='$product_id',product_name='$product_name',quantity='$quantity',unit='$unit',unit_rate='$unit_rate' where purchase_id='$purchase_id'");

        $i++;
    }   

            }




        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();        
        return $success;
    }
```

Save code is working correctly but at the time of editing only newly inserted record is saved to database. This is the code for getting product details from database and storing them in session at the time of editing..

```
function get_update_product(){

        $purchase_id=$_POST['purchase_id'];
        if($purchase_id!=''){
            //$post_array['cart']='';
            $res = $this->db->query("select * from phppos_productdetails WHERE purchase_id='$purchase_id'");
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Product  Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Unit Rate</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $i=0;
            foreach($res->result() as $row ){
                $sess_products[$i]['product_id'] = $row->product_id;
                $sess_products[$i]['quantity'] = $row->quantity;
                $sess_products[$i]['unit'] = $row->unit;
                $sess_products[$i]['unit_rate'] = $row->unit_rate;

                $this->session->set_userdata('sess_products',$sess_products);
                //$post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('sess_products');

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM phppos_items WHERE item_id='".$row->product_id."'");
                foreach($query->result() as $row1 ){
                    $product_name=$row1->name;

                }
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$row->product_id."' name='product_id[]'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='hidden'  style='width:80%;'  value='".$product_name."' name='product_name[]'/></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='width:40%;'>".$product_name."</td>";

                echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row->quantity."' name='quantity[]'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row->unit."' name='unit[]'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:100%;' value='".$row->unit_rate."' name='unit_rate[]'/></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_update_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $i++;

            }


        }
    }
```

Anybody has any idea about this??

Answer (score 0):

You can update your session in codeigniter by following line

```
$this->session->set_userdata('your_session_variable',$products);
```

Comment: where do I put this line??

Comment: U have many options .... if  u add second product then append with first one and save in single array ... then u can insert in db

Comment: I am appending correctly but at the time of insert, it insert only newly added record..

Comment: then your insert query is wrong..check your loop..how many times it runs and count your array first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69436/discussion-between-vignesh-and-kedar-b).